# How to make a UITextView stay scrolled at the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, scroll, uitextview

I was programming away when i came across a problem with my UITextView,
what i want is for it to be sort of anchored to the bottom of the UITextView, Since my app automatically adds lines and text i need the UITextView to stay at the bottom, so the user can read them as they are coming through. Now i have found a way to do this but its using scrolling and it cant keep up with the rate the app is typing or it jumps to far and then you cant see anything and it just looks messy, so here is the code

```
 CGPoint scrollPoint = self.codeBox.contentOffset; // initial and after update

scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, scrollPoint.y +1); // makes scroll
[self.codeBox setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
```

So like i said i want to find a way to have the UITextView so it stays hooked on the bottom without any of the messy scrolling. Any help would be much appreciated and P.S i am new to Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated` (a method of UIScrollView, of which UITextView is a subclass)
or
`- (void)scrollRangeToVisible:(NSRange)range` which is more specific to UITextView